# Not sure whats wrong with my SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm only just starting out in SQL land and am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with one of my tables. I have as followed

```
CREATE TABLE Winemaker ( 
Winemaker_id varchar (20) NOT NULL, 
Winemaker_name varchar (20) NOT NULL, 
key (Winemaker_Id)); 

CREATE TABLE Wine ( 
Wine_Id varchar (20) NOT NULL, 
Wine_name varchar (20) NOT NULL, 
Winemaker_Id varchar (4) NOT NULL, 
Wine_vintage varchar (8) NOT NULL, 
Wine_price varchar (8) NOT NULL 
Primary key (Wine_Id) 
Foreign key (Winemaker_Id) REFERENCES Winemaker(Id));
```

I am not quite sure what I've done wrong. If anyone could help that would be great, thanks!

Comment: extra semicolon(;) before `REFERENCES`.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What error?  There are a few syntax errors but they should be preventing either table from being created.

Comment: I get the error code 'missing right parenthesis at line 8'.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues, mostly around the definition of the foreign key reference.  Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Winemaker ( 
    Winemaker_id varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    Winemaker_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    primary key (Winemaker_Id)
); 

CREATE TABLE Wine ( 
    Wine_Id varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    Wine_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    Winemaker_Id varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    Wine_vintage varchar(8) NOT NULL, 
    Wine_price varchar (8) NOT NULL,
    Primary key (Wine_Id),
    Foreign key (Winemaker_Id) REFERENCES Winemaker(Winemaker_id)
);
```

SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88da5).

Notes:

- You need to define a primary key (or at least unique key) on `Winemaker` to have a foreign key reference to it.
- The data type of the column in the referencing table needs to exactly match the data type in the referenced table.
- You had missing commas.
- You had extra closing parens and semicolons.
- Also, spaces between `varchar` and `(` are allowed, but they look awkward.

Comment: Thank you very much that has worked! I'll also keep the pointers in mind for next time.